# When I boot up Kubuntu, It shows "x86:\cpu disabled by BIOS. DMAR: Failed to find the handle for ACPI object"

Tags: boot, kubuntu

DMAR: Failed to find the handle for ACPI object
When I boot it shows like this for few minutes, but it boots into the system. Still I want to resolve this issue.

Before booting:

[image]

```
x86/cpu: disabled by BIOS 
DMAR: Failed to find the handle for ACPI object
```